# std::for_each and two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, stl

I have defined two dimensional array using following definition
`typedef std::vector<std::vector<short> > table_t;`

Can I use `std::for_each` for this array, I want to pass `row` and `col` as a parameter to the `function`

Or is there a way to identify `row` and `col` in the `function`

following is the code to get more idea.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::vector<std::vector<short> > table_t;

void myfunction (int i) {
    std::cout << " " << i;
}
int main ( int argc , char **argv) {
    table_t t = table_t(5, std::vector<short>(5));
    int counter = 0;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
           for (size_t col = 0; col < 5; ++col)
               t[row][col] = counter++;

    std::for_each( t.begin(), t.end(), myfunction);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think  the solution is custom function object. Try something like this:

```
struct process_col
{
      int row_index;
      int col_index;
      process_col(int r) : row_index(r), col_index(0){}
      void operator()(short & data)
      {
          //use row_index, col_index, and data at this indices

           std::cout << "Value at (" <<row_index <<"," << col_index << ") is " << data << std::endl;

           col_index++; //at the bottom
      }
};

struct process_row
{
      int row_index;
      process_row() : row_index(0){}
      void operator()(std::vector<short> & row)
      {
         std::for_each(row.begin(), row.end(), process_col(row_index));
         row_index++;
      }
};
```

And then use it as:

```
std::for_each( t.begin(), t.end(), process_row());
```

Online Demo : http://ideone.com/Dft8X

Output:

```
Value at (0,0) is 0
Value at (0,1) is 1
Value at (0,2) is 2
Value at (0,3) is 3
Value at (0,4) is 4
Value at (1,0) is 5
Value at (1,1) is 6
Value at (1,2) is 7
Value at (1,3) is 8
Value at (1,4) is 9
Value at (2,0) is 10
Value at (2,1) is 11
Value at (2,2) is 12
Value at (2,3) is 13
Value at (2,4) is 14
Value at (3,0) is 15
Value at (3,1) is 16
Value at (3,2) is 17
Value at (3,3) is 18
Value at (3,4) is 19
Value at (4,0) is 20
Value at (4,1) is 21
Value at (4,2) is 22
Value at (4,3) is 23
Value at (4,4) is 24
```

Comment: Does not work, getting following error :
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'process_col'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=short
1>        ]
1>        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
error C2676: binary '++' : 'std::vector<_Ty>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=short
1>        ]
error C2275: 'process_row' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: @Avinash: See the online demo (I've provided the link). You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Avinash: Write `process_row()`, not `process_row`. Similarly, `process_col(row_index)`, not `process_col`.

Comment: @Avinash: In your code, see there is member variable named `row`, but the same name you've used for parameter name also which is also `row`.  Look at my code : http://ideone.com/Dft8X

Answer (score 2):

**c++98**

```
void SomeThingElse(int row, int col)
{  
  // Impl.
}

struct Fun
{
     private:
        int col_m; 
        int row_m;
     public:
        Fun(int row) : row_m(row) { }
        void operator()(int x) const
        {
            SomeThingElse(row_m, x);
        }
};
void SomeFun(const std::vector<short>& cols)
{
   static int row = 0;
   ++row;
   std::for_each( cols.begin(), cols.end(), Fun(row));
}    


std::for_each(table_t.begin(), table_t.end(), SomeFun);
```

**c++11.** ( Just to show how easy it would be ). **( EDIT )**

```
int row = 0;
std::for_each( begin(table_t), end(table_t), [&]( const std::vector<short>& col)
{
    row++;
    int temp = row;
    std::for_each( begin(col), end(col), [=](int x )
    {
          fn(temp, x);   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, I think you'd want `std::array<std::array<short, 5> ,5>` intead of the vector-of-vector (making sure all rows are of equal length and optimizing storage).

If your compiler already supports *template aliases* you can use one to get 'pretty' declaration:

```
template <class T, size_t R, size_t C>   
     using matrix = std::array<std::array<T, C>, R>;    

// use it simply like:
matrix<short, 5, 5> t;
```

Here is a rough draft that can do both, based on C++11

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename M, typename F>
    void for_matrix(M& matrix, F f)
{
    size_t r = 0;
    for (auto& row : matrix)
    {
        size_t c = 0;
        for (auto& cell : row)
            f(cell, r, c++);
        r++;
    }
}


void sample_function(short& data, size_t row, size_t col)
{
    std::cout << "(" << row << ", " << col << "): " << data << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // based on vector:
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<short> > table_t;
    table_t t = table_t(5, std::vector<short>(5));

    for_matrix(t, sample_function);
    for_matrix(t, [] (short&i,size_t,size_t) { std::cout << "lambda: " << i << std::endl; });

    // based on std::array:
    std::array<std::array<short, 3>, 4> a;
    for_matrix(a, [] (short&i,size_t,size_t) { i = 0; });
    for_matrix(a, sample_function);
}
```